# iOS Wake Up App For Local Notification

Tags: ios, notifications, local

I am trying to create local notifications.  I got the notifications working, but with a hard coded title.  I need to be able to wake up the app, hit an api, and then present the notification to the user with the title returned from the api call.  Can someone suggest what method(s) I should use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make that API call when you are setting up the local notification? If so just set the local notifications alertBody to the title you retrive from your API.

Comment: No, I have to make the api call the same time the local notification is created.  for example, every so often, the app will wake up, and check for what the latest product offer is.  it will then display to the user a notification:  "20% off these new sneakers!" or whatever.  But it doesnt know about the sneakers until it wakes up and checks with the web service.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using local notifications, but would be possible using push notifications.
Is there any reason why you aren't using push notifications?